# Echo when recording and playing sound

Tags: java, audio

I have a simple application that starts recording from the microphone and then immediately plays the sounds back to my headphones, however the problem here is: the sound quality is not good and there is a lasting echo after speaking something in the microphone which can last up to 5 seconds after speaking. I'm not sure whether the problem lies in the Java Sound API and I need to switch to another library.

I also want to mention that I use a headphone that is plugged into my computer. When I use low volume then the sound plays normal however when I turn it up to 90% of my maximum value the sound quality really becomes bad.

Here is my code:

```
AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED, 44100, 16, 2, 4, 44100, false);
    
    DataLine.Info dataLineInfo = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, format);
    TargetDataLine mic = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(dataLineInfo);
    mic.open();
    mic.start();
    
    DataLine.Info dataLineInfo2 = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, format);
    SourceDataLine speakers = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(dataLineInfo2);
    speakers.open();
    speakers.start();
    
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    
    
    while(true) {
        mic.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
        
        speakers.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
        
    }
```

Comment: I tried the code myself but there doesn't seem to be any problems for me, no echoing and no bad quality audio. If you have another machine or another microphone try using it there.

Comment: I have tried other microphones and speakers but the problem stayed the same, for audio output i am using headphones. Could this possibly be the cause of latency?

Comment: So my headphones are connected to my computer, at lower volume sounds there is no error and no echo however when i turn up the volume to 90% of max then i clearly hear an echo and bad sound quality.

Comment: Here's a thought: unplug your headset and play the sample through your speakers. Doing so is more or less a formality at this point since you seem to have worked through the process of elimination already.

Comment: Loud head speakers may not be a convention but it still is a problem for anyone who decides to use headphones at a high volume. I'm not sure what exactly causes this problem. And i'm not sure what you mean with elimination.

Comment: Any this occurs with really anything headphones or speakers. If the volume increases the sound quality decreases.

Comment: Possibilities: (1) the mic line is simply over-driving the playback line, (2) mic is picking up the sound from the headphones and creating feedback, (3) you have a really high buffer size and this is contributing to the latency.

Comment: hi @PhilFreihofner. What could be the possible solution for these 3 possibilities ? can you please explain a bit ?

Comment: Stackoverflow doesn't like us to use comments for conversation. And without more specifics, you question is too open-ended for me to give a concise answer. I am going to have to limit myself to directing you to the tutorials, which at least gives background on how to vary and test line volumes and buffer sizes for troubleshooting. IDK how one deals with mike picking up sounds that are in the air--get better headphones and don't play them so loud? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/sampled-overview.html Good background over course of sound.sampled section of tuts.